# how to get policy name by AuthorizationHandlerContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

This is how to authorize inside my controller's method

```
    [Authorize(Policy = "MyCustomPolicy")]
    public .....MyMethod(..,..)
```

This is `HandleRequirementAsync`

```
    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
```

I want to get policy name `MyCustomPolicy` inside this Handler.

Comment: This is not possible, unfortunately.

Comment: Why not pass the policy name by the [Requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.2#requirements) instead?